# Golang: how to write common function, only can be used by _test file, and these function would be invisible for non test files

Tags: go

Golang: how to write common function, only can be used by *_test file, and these function would be invisible for non test files.

Comment: Put it in a file named with `_test.go` suffix

Comment: If by "common" you mean shared by different packages then that's no possible, it is not possible to declare function that can be imported only by test files. If you need common functionality for tests-only simply create a normal package, put code specifically designed for testing in it, name the package as such and you're done. As an example see: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/ and https://golang.org/pkg/testing/iotest/

Answer (score 2):

## Making test functions invisible for non test files

By just including the `_test.go` suffix, all non test files will not be able to see any functions.

**In the go stdlib**, they use the technique of creating an `export_test.go` for all exported test functions. See [this example](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/reflect/export_test.go) in the reflection test package. I feel that this is the better answer than just the `_test.go` package.